# A SF Book set in a Cyberpunk universe

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, cyberpunk, sentience

The book is about a guy (I think he is a young adult) who makes a living by giving ideas away in exchange for services.

There is a scene about him and a few other guys and 1 girl about them talking of how to save a species of virtual sentient crabs into space.

The beginning of the book has a conversation between him and a soviet AI.

I had it as an audio-book so I do not know anything about the year it was made or how the cover might have looked. The main character (the guy I talked about) did not like the idea of having to deal with currency and his family (his sister I think) always kept criticizing him about his lifestyle. The conversation with the AI was when he was sitting at a cafe. The Crab situation was in a sort of club. He and the others mentioned where contemplating the faith of some virtualised crabs that turned sentient. He managed to send them on a satellite to save them.

Comment: Did it involve alternate universes? And there's a list of things to add to your question at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info. Very importantly, when and where did you read this?

Comment: No alternate universes that i remember.

Comment: Well so much for one of the Long Earth books (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Earth_(series)) :)

Comment: I know I have read this, but a long time ago. I *think* it is Bruce Sterling; possibly The Zenith Angle, or maybe The Caryatids.

Comment: The problem is that i had it as an audio-book so i do not know anything about the year it was made or how the cover might have looked.

The main character (the guy i talked about) did not like the idea of having to deal with currency and his family (his sister i think) always kept criticizing him about his lifestyle.

The conversation with the AI was when he was sitting at a cafe.

The Crab situation was in a sort of club.
He and the others mentioned where contemplating the faith of some virtualsed crabs that turned sentient. He managed to send them on a satelite to save them.

Comment: It's lobsters, not crabs. But otherwise you've summarised the first part of the book pretty well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it is [Accelerando](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/fiction/accelerando/accelerando-intro.html) by Charles Stross. About the singularity, and developing new reputational economics, told through interconnected shorter stories, including the uploaded lobsters sent in to space, the AI cat, the dominatrix wife.
Good book!

Comment: That is it! 

Thank you!

Comment: @Astearon
Please click the checkmark to accept then.